# What is the best solution to this issue regarding collapsing toolbar, occurring due to object animator?

Tags: android, animation

I have an Activity with upper ui like below:
[image]

when I scroll up the list, i should hide the title bar(not action bar but one LinearLayout in my layout) so I used below code:

```
    private void hideTitleBar() {
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(***titleLin***, "translationY", -titleLin.getHeight()).setDuration(300);
    animator.start();
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(selectTitleView, "translationY", -titleLin.getHeight()).setDuration(300).start();
    isTitleVisible = false;
    Log.d("","title bar hide, brandSortView is:"+brandSortView.getMainView().getHeight());
}
```

titleLin is the above title, but what I got is below image:

[image]

and below is my layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rl_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/title_lin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/title_bg_height"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title_lin">
  //other things........

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_lin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_active" />
```

this is quite strange because when i call directly titleLine.setVisibility(View.GONE), the title just disapeared but the ui effect is not good.

Any one has some idea?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your **actual requirement** in comments here. I can safely say t**his is not the way to achieve that onscroll effect**. **Correct way is to use a coordinator layout**. Using it you can create very beautiful custom onscroll animations:

> This is an example of how coordinator layout with scrolling toolbar  might look in xml

**This is the xml code for [this](http://androcode.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/simple_coordinator.gif) example.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/material_flat"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="@string/lorem"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Source: [Saúl Molinero](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)

For more indepth understanding you can have a look at google official docs as well [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)

Hope this info helps you.

**EDIT**: As mentioned in code that you really can't do a lot of refactoring and need a solution that involves **object animator** . I would like to suggest you to use **Animation listener** and in your **onAnimationEnd()** you should remove the view and animate the other views to the desired position.

Please have a look at these [official Google docs regarding same](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)

Comment: no this is the same effect as "having no animation", the ui flicker when the title hide.

Comment: Tell me more about your animation. How do you want the title to go and on which condition ? like when user scrolls or something.

Comment: when user scroll up the title move out of screen (up) with 300ms animation, and scroll down the title come back with 300ms animation

Comment: @tainy Please check my updated answer. It is perfect solution to your problem. Would really appreciate if you could upvote and accept my answer. Good Luck

Comment: thank you very much but this is not in my choice temporarily. The code I took is quite big and related to others. Unless I have time to refactor, I cannot change the layout in that way.

Comment: I understand. But then it's not possible or even feasible to do It any other way. You won't get similar results and would end up wasting your time and energy. But if later you feel my answer is the only way left to achieve your goal then please do consider upvoting and accepting it :) . Also if you find a good solution to achieve same smooth, well tuned effect do comment here and let me know. I will be interested in knowing that too.

Comment: I have tried one last time to help you with that to best of my knowledge as of now. Please check new EDITED answer. Unfortunately I can't think of anything else regarding this issue. But will surely let you know if I figure something out.

Comment: thank you very much Nishant! I have upvoted for your effect!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution for that:
**Cause**: it is caused by the blank in the parent layout is not filled by the remaining parts when I move the title out. Further if I remove the title manually at the end of the animation, the UI flickered.

**Solution**: It is simply resolved by layout animation,very simple and clean, please refer to below if you are not familiar.
[Animating Layout Changes from Android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html)